# Slideshow type Transition of image using single ImageView

Tags: android, android-glide, android-transitions

I've a RecyclerView with list of imageviews in it. I want to randomly change the image in the ImageView after every few seconds and image should slide in from any direction while exiting the previous image to the other direction (kind of a slide show). Currently, I'm using Glide transition but it does half of the work, it translates the view from left or right but doesn't give effect of exiting the previous image. My question is that is it possible by using only single ImageView or i need to use more than one imageviews or a ViewPager instead?

Comment: use `ImageSwitcher`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using databinding and loading image with Glide, how will it work with that? if i set data factory on each imageUrl change then won't it be expensive task?

Comment: I've explored it and it is really nice widget but the output is same like using Glide transition because it is still not showing 2 images together, i entering and other exiting. Any idea?

Comment: did you use both animations? in and out?

Comment: yes.   can the reason be that ImageSwitcher is not creating 2 ImageViews?

Comment: you have to create them

Comment: I've set Factory and I've that it is called 'makeView' twice but still transition happens for 1 view.

Comment: no, if you use both animations then both `ImageView`s are animated

Comment: Used both animations, here is the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346477/imageswitcher-is-not-showing-outanimation

Comment: Please see the given link it has code of animation as well

Comment: https://codeshare.io/arrywv

Comment: unfortunately result is still the same :/

Comment: I just changed resource on click and it worked fine even with my code., but when i set resource in onResouceReady method of Glide, it causes issue again. I'm updating image url each after 5 seconds that updates image with Glide using databinding.

Comment: `setImageDrawable` should work too - i didnt test it though...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) . Issue was with ' .thumbnail(.1f)' of Glide request.